# PostDialogListener() android Facebook api issue

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to create a small app that posts the entries made by an user in my app to facebook when they press the back button to quit. I already have SSO and everything else set up, the problem is it does not recognize PostDialogListener as a valid listener. Says does not exist, the code where I am trying to use it

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
         Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");

         fb.dialog(getApplicationContext(), "stream.publish", new PostDialogListener());

         Toast t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Back pressed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         t.show();
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

I tried putting the dialog code in other places too, but same result, PostDialogListener is not being recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't import it from example. Add these classes to your project:

```
public abstract class BaseDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }
}

public class PostDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            showToast("Message posted on the wall.");
        } else {
            showToast("No message posted on the wall.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have the same issue with requestlistener, so you saying I have to implement every listener ?

Comment: You can take imalementation from Facebook SDK examples

Comment: hey thanks, i thought they were inbuilt methods! Now its working fine, but still I don't know how to get the proper fb dialog saying, do you want to post it to your wall.

Comment: "how to get the proper fb dialog saying" - I don't understand this sentence. You can see an example of proper work using Facebook SDK in my project - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Social-Sharing